# How to make a variable in service global

Tags: angularjs

```
function getEmails() {

  return $http.get('/api/email')
         .success(function(data) {
           var messages = data;
         })
};
```

I have this function defined inside a service, how do i make messages accessible in the service and to other functions in same service

Answer (score 0):

Declare a variable inside the service and use it

```
messages :any;

function getEmails() {
   return $http.get('/api/email')
        .success(function(data) {
           this.messages = data;
        })
};
```

Comment: var messages;

    function getEmails() {

       return $http.get('/api/email')
            .success(function(data) {
               this.messages = data;
            })
    };

      console.log(messages) in console i am getting messages undefined

Comment: try console.log(this.messages);

Comment: still getting undefined